# Gulp-cli version is not updating

Tags: npm, gulp

I've updated gulp from v `3.9.0` to `4.0.0`. When I run `gulp` i get error `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`. I've read that this is because of gulp-cli version `3.9.0` and I need to update to `2.1.0`

On my local machine i've got all to work, and the versions are:

```
CLI Version: 2.1.0
Local Version: 4.0.0
```

But on our dev-server the CLI-version won't change and it's stuck at `3.9.0`.

I have uninstalled both gulp and gulp-cli, removed the node_modules folder. Installed it again and it's the correct versions in the `package.json`.

```
"gulp": "^4.0.0",
"gulp-cli": "^2.1.0",
```

But when i run `gulp -v` now it still outputs `CLI Version: 3.9.0`..

Someone familiar with this? `gulp 3.9.0` is globally installed on the server, can this cause the problem?

Answer (score 3):

First uninstall your current versions of Gulp and Gulp CLI:

```
npm uninstall gulp --save-dev
npm uninstall gulp -g
```

then go ahead and reinstall Gulp version 4.0.0:

```
npm install gulp-cli -g
npm install gulp@4.0.0
```

Comment: When installing `gulp` back you should use `--save-dev` option in order to save the changes in the `package.json`:  `npm install --save-dev gulp@4.0.0`.

Comment: The line `npm uninstall gulp -g` should read `npm uninstall gulp-cli -g`.